# Separating two arrays returned from mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have created this

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($course_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($data['course']);   
}
```

Which prints this:

```
Array ( 
     [user_id] => 57 
     [course] => 6 
)
Array ( 
     [user_id] => 57 
     [course] => 5 
)
```

How can I create two variables that are equal to the values of the 'course' fields.
So ideally, variable `x` ends up equalling to 6 and variable `y` equals 5 (essentially what I'm asking is how to  extract the value from the mysql arrays and putting it into a variable)?

Comment: Will they always be `6`/`5`, or will it always be 1st result as `x` and 2nd result as `y`, and will there always just be 2 rows returned?

Comment: @Sean no, the value of the course field won't always be 6/5. So yes, the 1st result = x, the second equal to y.

Comment: So there will never be more than two results from the query? What's the likelihood of needing a 3rd, 4th and so on variable?

Comment: `while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($course_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { if(!isset($x)){$x=$data['course']['course'];}else{$y=$data['course']['course'];} }`. This assumes only 2 rows returned from your query, and that it is only called once, as once `$x` is set, it won't be reset, and `$y` would continue to be reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no something as you called "mysql_arrays". They are normal arrays.

You can do for example:

```
$array = array();
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($course_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $array[] = $data; // probably this way and not $array[] = $data['course'];
}  

$x = $array[0]['course'];
$y = $array[1]['course'];
```

Comment: also there is array_column function which can help you with the above ans..check the link ..http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using an array instead of a variable to store the values.

```
$arr= array();
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($course_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $arr[] = $data['course'];
}
```

Comment: note it should be `$arr[] = $data['course']['course']` as according to the OP's code -> `print_r($data['course']);` returns `Array ( [user_id] => 57 [course] => 6 )`

Answer (score 0):

Speculating a bit as don't have the full picture but I guess you're after something like this.

Get an array of the courses from your data

```
$data = array_map(function($value) {
    return $value['course'];
}, $data);
```

If there are only ever two results, assign each one to a variable :

```
list($x, $y) = $data;
```

If there are more than two results, you have an array of courses in `$data` from your query results.